# undefined method `merge_cells' RubyXL

Tags: ruby

I am using rubyXL and when I am trying to call merge_cells on a worksheet I am getting

```
undefined method `merge_cells' for #<RubyXL::Worksheet:0x007fda50159bb8>

@workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
worksheet = @workbook[0]
worksheet.merge_cells(0, 0, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

[As of version `3.4.0`](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL#convenience-methods) of `rubyXL`, you need to:

```
require 'rubyXL/convenience_methods/worksheet'
```

You can also see this in [the tests](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL/blob/535885e8b6ee7c34edcc8f7639709094fba98341/spec/lib/worksheet_spec.rb#L2), where the method is later [called](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL/blob/535885e8b6ee7c34edcc8f7639709094fba98341/spec/lib/worksheet_spec.rb#L568).

This works as expected:

```
require 'rubyXL/convenience_methods/worksheet'

@workbook = RubyXL::Workbook.new
worksheet = @workbook[0]
worksheet.merge_cells(0, 0, 0, 1)
# => [#<RubyXL::MergedCell:0x00007fe5b6ac5320 @local_namespaces=nil, @ref=#<RubyXL::Reference @row_range=0..0 @col_range=0..1>>]
```